# How do you handle cross origin with Angular 2 + Django during development?

Tags: angularjs, django, google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain

I'm using Angular CLI to run my SPA during development. It launches a dev server directly in memory with hot reload and all cool stuff. I'm using Django as my back-end and Django has its own development server. Naturally they respond from different ports and this seems to be a problem for browsers.

How am I supposed to handle this?

I can switch off CSRF in Django, but even then I have to start Chrome with some special flags that allows it to connect to my dev back-end. Firefox doesn't work at all. Security is a great thing, but I'd like to develop my application after all. I have no idea how I can test with Firefox without making a production build running on Apache together with the back-end.

Comment: Would Django CORS work? You could conditional-ize the code in your `settings.py` to only run when `DEBUG= True`. https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, thanks.